# fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros2, tf2, ros-humble, cv-bridge

Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble

I have a [blickfield](https://www.blickfeld.com/resources/) lidar and they provide ROS2 foxy support. I have downloaded the [blickfield_ros2_driver](https://github.com/ashBabu/blickfeld_ros2_driver) from their website and created a repository.

**Aim:** I want to get it working in ROS2 Humble

I am basically following their [Readme](https://github.com/ashBabu/blickfeld_ros2_driver?tab=readme-ov-file#blickfeld-ros2-package). However when I do `colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-clean-first`, I get the following

```
[ash@bot] [~/ros2_ws] - colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-clean-first
Starting >>> ouster_sensor_msgs
Starting >>> blickfeld_driver
Starting >>> pmd_royale_ros
Starting >>> pmd_royale_ros_driver
Starting >>> pmd_royale_ros_examples                                                                                                          
Finished <<< pmd_royale_ros [0.37s]                                                                                                    
--- stderr: blickfeld_driver                                                                                                                             
CMake Deprecation Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:32 (message):
  Use rosidl_get_typesupport_target() and target_link_libraries() instead of
  rosidl_target_interfaces()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:102 (rosidl_target_interfaces)


WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_lib" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_lib" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_component" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_component" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_node" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_node" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_core" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "blickfeld_driver_core" requests linking to directory "/usr/include".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
/home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/src/blickfeld_driver_utils.cpp:14:10: fatal error: cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h: No such file or directory
   14 | #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/build.make:118: modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/src/blickfeld_driver_utils.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/src/blickfeld_driver_point_cloud_parser.cpp:15:
/home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/include/blickfeld_driver_core/blickfeld_driver_point_cloud_parser.h:16:10: fatal error: cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/build.make:104: modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/src/blickfeld_driver_point_cloud_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/include/blickfeld_driver_core/blickfeld_driver_core.h:24,
                 from /home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/src/blickfeld_driver_core.cpp:17:
/home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/include/blickfeld_driver/blickfeld_driver_ros_types.h:14:10: fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h: No such file or directory
   14 | #include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/build.make:76: modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/src/blickfeld_driver_core.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/include/blickfeld_driver_core/blickfeld_driver_imu_parser.h:20,
                 from /home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/src/blickfeld_driver_imu_parser.cpp:12:
/home/ash/ros2_ws/src/ros2_blickfeld_driver/include/blickfeld_driver/blickfeld_driver_ros_types.h:14:10: fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h: No such file or directory
   14 | #include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/build.make:90: modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/src/blickfeld_driver_imu_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:727: modules/ros_blickfeld_driver_core/CMakeFiles/blickfeld_driver_core.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< blickfeld_driver [3.54s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< ouster_sensor_msgs [3.57s]
Aborted  <<< pmd_royale_ros_examples [8.83s]                                                                                     
Aborted  <<< pmd_royale_ros_driver [10.2s]                                  

Summary: 1 package finished [10.7s]
  1 package failed: blickfeld_driver
  3 packages aborted: ouster_sensor_msgs pmd_royale_ros_driver pmd_royale_ros_examples
  1 package had stderr output: blickfeld_driver
  1 package not processed
```

I think the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ashBabu/blickfeld_ros2_driver/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) has properly linked to both `cv_bridge` and `tf2_geometry_msgs`. I even tried to change the `.h` to `.hpp` but did not work.

I have already done `sudo apt install ros-humble-cv-bridge/tf2-geometry-msgs`. Something I observed is that if I go to `/opt/ros/humble/include/`, all the similar msgs are under a `msg` folder where as tf2-geometry-msgs are not. Is my installation okay?

Any help would be really appreciated. TIA